# How to use QGraphicsScene::setStyle()?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I am using `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to embed `QWidget`s inside a `QGraphicsScene`. The problem comes with the style with which these widgets are drawed.
From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html):

> A top-level item's style defaults to QGraphicsScene::style.   A top-level widget's style defaults to QApplication::style

So, I have to set the style to `QGraphicsScene`. Right now, I am using `QWidget::setStyleSheet` to set custom styles based on CSS (QSS).

My question is: how can I use `QGraphicsScene::setStyle`, which requires an instance of `QStyle`, since I haven't got one? Can somebody post an example using it and setting a stylesheet-enabled style?

I have already tried `QStyleFactory::create`, but there is no way to create an instance of `QStyleSheetStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't got an instance of `QStyle`, the default style used for a `QGraphicsScene` is `QApplication::style()`, as it is stated in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#setStyle).

> The scene's style defaults to QApplication::style(), and serves as the
>   default for all QGraphicsWidget items in the scene.

The second part of this sentence implies that you can customize your widgets inside a scene (like you are doing right now with `QWidget::setStyleSheet`). You can assign a style sheet to a widget before adding it into the scene, it will keep its style after being added.

But it is not possible for a `QGraphicsScene`, since it has not such a function. **Their style should be defined by using a `QPalette` and set via [QApplication::setPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#palette-prop).** Remember that QGraphicsScene also has functions like [setBackgroundBrush](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#backgroundBrush-prop) and [setForegroundBrush](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#foregroundBrush-prop).

```
QPalette pal;
pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor(255, 0, 0));

QApplication::setPalette(pal);

QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(400,400,400,400);
scene->setPalette(pal);

QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
view->show();
```

Comment: Ok, I have gone with the `QWidget::setStyleSheet` way as you said, and it works pretty fine. I will accept your answer for this, regardless it doesn't show how to use `QGraphicsScene::setStyle`. Thank you anyway, since you showed me a workaround.

Comment: In fact you can't if you don't have your own style. You can do `setStyle(QApplication::style())` (it is by default) but you still have to change the default style if you want something to be changed